# Background Image covering JComponents

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to make a registration form for a game(assignment) for school and i have finished it but i wanted to add an image on it but it blocks everything, JButton,JTextField etc.. How can i fix this? ***EDITED : I MADE THE CODE A LITTLE SHORTER SAME PROBLEM OCCURS.***

```
public class MyGUI {


JLabel xyz;
JButton b1;



public JPanel createContentPane () {



    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(null);

    xyz = new JLabel("Don't have an account? Sign up!");
    xyz.setBounds(10,0,390,30);
    xyz.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 20));
    xyz.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    mainPanel.add(xyz);


    b1 = new JButton("Create Account");
    b1.setBounds(40,540,310,33);
    b1.setFont(new Font("Comic San Ms", Font.BOLD , 16));
    b1.setForeground(Color.white);
    b1.setBackground(Color.blue);
    mainPanel.add(b1);

    return mainPanel;
}

public static void CreateAndShowGUI()  {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Romaverse ONLINE! REGISTRATION");

    Container c = frame.getContentPane();
    MyGUI demo = new MyGUI();
    c.add(demo.createContentPane());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(480,700);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\roma.jpg")));


}



public static void main(String[] args)  {


      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                    CreateAndShowGUI();
                    }       
                           });
                }

            }
```

Here Is the part where i put the image

```
frame.setContentPane(newJLabel(newImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\roma.jpg"));
```

[image: ERROR IMAGE IS BLOCKING IT]
[image: This is where i take the image off]

Comment: You want background image.. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Satya Edited, See outputs above first picture is when i add this line frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\roma.jpg"))); i dont want it to block the jbutton and other things i want it to be transparent or behind.

Comment: @LoraGonzales Try using graphics to paint the image.

Comment: @RHA Edited, i made it shorter same problem just with less things.

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers to you don't worry about pixel placement of components. Use an appropriate layout manager (or combination of nested layout managers) to get the desired layout.

Comment: You add the login form to the content pane and THEN you REPLACE the content pane with something else ... and you wonder why the form isn't displayed

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/).

It shows two approaches:

1. Add the image to a JLabel and then add your components to the label
2. Do custom painting of the image on a JPanel and then add your components to the panel.

Edit:

Basic code using approach 1:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
label.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
label.add( new JButton("Hello") );
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add( background );
```

Comment: Still doesnt work though. i tried making a JLabel and setting the image there.

Comment: @LoraGonzales, yes it works. You already know how to add an image to a label because you posted a picture in your question. Now you just add the controls to the label. and add the label to the frame. Update your short example that shows where you add the controls to the label NOT the JPanel. See edit for the basic steps.

Comment: I figured out why it doesn't show i'm suppose to do label.setSize(num,num);

Comment: @LoraGonzales, `i'm suppose to do label.setSize(num,num);` - no you are not supposed to do that. The JLabel will determine its own size based on the size of the image. That is why you were told NOT to use a null layout. I gave you the basic code an nowhere in that code to I set the size of any component. Learn to use Swing properly and you won't have these bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The image doesn't block buttons, it *replaces* them because you are calling `setContentPane`. Why are you doing this? You can simply add the image together with all other controls inside the `createContentPane` method. Note that the order in which controls are added may affect their Z-order.